# Boost.Python + OpenGL segmentation faults

Tags: python, memory, opengl, boost, segmentation-fault

I have a (almost) perfectly working C++ code written with Boost.Python. It wraps a shared pointer based structure hierarchy of 3 or 4 classes, nothing terribly complex (i.e. class A has a std::vector of class B instance pointers, etc.), top level package called, say, foo.

Some time ago I decided to add visualization to the project using PyOpenGL. So now, whenever I have `import OpenGL` before I have `import foo`, I'm getting segmentation faults inside C++ code (such as when I iterate over a sequence of objects and their child objects.)

My best assumption is that OpenGL somehow substitutes memory allocation functions or does something similarly unholy. Any one can shed some light on the situation? I'll try to provide more details on request, but the whole thing seems to be rather chaotic.

On request, isolated test case:

Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -shared -o foo.so -fPIC \
        -I/usr/include/boost-1_37/ -I/usr/include/python2.5 \
        -lpython2.5 -lboost_python-1_37 \
        foo.cpp
```

Python file:

```
from OpenGL import *
import foo

b = foo.B()

for i in range(10):
    b.elements.append(foo.A())

for e in b.elements:
    print e

# Crash here if `from OpenGL import *` is present.
```

C++ file:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace bp = boost::python;

struct A {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr;
};

struct B {
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<B> ptr;
    std::vector<A::ptr> elements;
};


// Proxies B::elements without converting them 
// back and forth between lists.
struct ElementProxy {

    static ElementProxy 
    init(B::ptr b)
    {
        return ElementProxy(b);
    }

    ElementProxy(B::ptr b)
    : b_(b)
    {}

    size_t
    len() 
    {
        return (*b_).elements.size();
    }

    A::ptr
    getitem(size_t i) 
    {
        if (i >= len()) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "Index out of bounds.");
            bp::throw_error_already_set();
        }
        return (*b_).elements[i];
    }

    void
    append(A::ptr e) 
    {
        (*b_).elements.push_back(e);
    }

    static boost::python::class_<ElementProxy> 
    wrap() 
    {
        return bp::class_<ElementProxy>("ElementProxy", bp::no_init)

            .def("__len__", &ElementProxy::len, 
                 (bp::arg("self")),
                 "Returns the number of contained elements"
                 )

            .def("__getitem__", &ElementProxy::getitem, 
                 (bp::arg("self"), bp::arg("i")), 
                 "Returns the element at given index"
                 )

            .def("append", &ElementProxy::append, 
                 (bp::arg("self"), bp::arg("element")), 
                 "Appends an element"
                 )
            ;
    }

private:

    B::ptr b_;
};



BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo) {

    bp::class_<A, A::ptr, boost::noncopyable>("A") ;

    ElementProxy::wrap();

    bp::class_<B, B::ptr, boost::noncopyable>("B")
        .add_property("elements", &ElementProxy::init) ;
}
```

Comment: Can you get this down to a minimal code sample?  Being able to look at it, and possibly to test it, will help a lot in trying to figure it out.

Comment: Modified the question to include one. In that particular case, the crash is after the loop, in the actual framework, it happens after the first `for` iteration.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Might not directly help, but.. generally its considered a bad idea to do "from SomeModule import *". Maybe try importing just what you need?

Comment: Good suggestion, but still no luck :( (ie. `from OpenGL import GL` still crashes)

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is linux, you might be running into this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/259219.

If calling

`export LD_PRELOAD=<path-to-libstdc++>`

before starting your program fixes it, this is it. You need to replace  with the actual path on your machine. Something like /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.1.2/libstdc++.so.6.

The bug only occurs for some graphics drivers and distributions, but it's quite widespread. In particular, it's fixed in Ubuntu 11.04.